# Create count ODBC with query

Tags: odbc, firebird, firebird2.5

It's possible insert a query in a count ODBC?

Example:

```sql
Select * From Customers where name = 'John';
```

I can't create a view in my database and I need to make that query in a Count ODBC to connect with Word.

Comment: Please edit your query while in actual form it is hard to say what problem you want to solve.

Comment: @user501007, what do you mean when you say "a Count ODBC"? ODBC is normally used to mean Open DataBase Connectivity - it's a way of connecting to databases, so the phrase "a Count ODBC" would normally be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to count customers with name 'John'?

If so then use:

```
Select count(*) From Customers where name = 'John';
```